# In Haskell, how can I replace an ASCII character sub-string in a ByteString?

Tags: haskell, bytestring

In [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/), how can I replace an [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character sub-string in a [`ByteString`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.4.0/docs/Data-ByteString.html)?  How can I use function [`replace`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stringsearch-0.3.3/docs/Data-ByteString-Search.html#g:7) in [`Data.ByteString.Search`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/stringsearch-0.3.3/docs/Data-ByteString-Search.html) using character strings as arguments?  Are there other ways to perform sub-string replacement in a `ByteString`?  For example, would it make sense to convert the `ByteString` to a `String`, perform the string substitution using the `String`, and then convert the result back to a `ByteString`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The string must be converted into a `ByteString` using [`pack`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.4.0/docs/Data-ByteString-Char8.html#v:pack).

If the string is a string literal, you can use the `OverloadedStrings` extension. This will convert automatically the string literal into a `ByteString`.

Comment: Do you mean I must first convert the string arguments to `ByteString` objects before I pass them to `replace`?  How do I generate the replacement string argument (the second argument) to `replace`?  The type of this argument must be an instance of `Substitution`.

Comment: Yes, you have to convert the string arguments into `ByteString` objects, and `ByteString` is an instance of the typeclass `Substitution`, so it is suitable as the second argument of `replace`.

Answer (score 2):

Example to illustrate Teetoo's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21991330/107158):

```
Prelude> :module + Data.ByteString.Char8 Data.ByteString.Search
Prelude Data.ByteString.Char8 Data.ByteString.Search> replace (pack "World") (pack "Derek") (pack "Hello, World!")
"Hello, Derek!"
Prelude Data.ByteString.Char8 Data.ByteString.Search>
```